# Why is Dart 2.12 a minor SDK upgrade when it breaks the previous code?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently, I'm have the following Dart SDK in my `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

But if I change it to the following and run `flutter pub get`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

I start getting errors for nullability. As far as I know this is supposed to be a minor change according to language versioning but I broke my code. Should't the addition of Null safety in Dart SDK considered a major upgrade like `3.0.0` as it breaks the existing code.

**Note**: I didn't run any command to opt-in for null safety.

Comment: "Note: I didn't run any command to opt-in for null safety." Yes you did, by changing the minsdk version.

Comment: Yes you're right, I shouldn't have changed it to `2.12` because it broke my code. So, it's a breaking change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try wording [Randal Schwartz's answer in a different way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67047063/179715):

*Using* the Dart 2.12 SDK does not require using null safety.  You can replace your existing Dart SDK installation with the Dart 2.12 SDK to use 2.12's tooling (e.g. to take advantage of better optimizations in the compiler, use new lints supported by the analyzer, new behavior in the formatter) and library implementations (i.e., to get bug fixes).  If that's *only* thing that you do, your existing code should not be broken.

Although enabling null safety breaks old code, the null safety feature is *opt-in*.  The mechanism to opt in to use null safety is to *separately* specify a *minimum* version of Dart 2.12 in your SDK requirements.  When you specify:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

that means that your code must remain compatible with Dart SDK version 2.6.0 (and therefore should not use any language features introduced after 2.6.0).  Since the Dart 2.12 SDK can provide such backward compatibility, it did not technically require a major version bump.

Comment: I tried this line of reasoning with OP.  They are too stubborn to yield to the truth, so I quit.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz "If you can't explain something in simple terms, you don't understand it." Thanks @ jamesdlin, I'll give it a read tomorrow.

Comment: @jamesdlin In your first paragraph you mentioned that I can use `2.12`'s tooling like compiler, analyzer, etc so sir, does flow analysis work if my code SDK is set to min `>=2.6.0 <3.0.0`?

Comment: No, setting your minimum SDK version to `>= 2.6.0` means that your code cannot depend on any language features after 2.6.0.  That means that your code would not be able to take advantage of new flow analysis since the compiler from 2.6.0 would reject it.

Comment: Sir, please type `@` to notify, I didn't get notification for couple of your comments lately. Coming to the question, as you said 2.12 is not a breaking change so how can I enable my code to use 2.12 features without breaking anything?

Comment: You.... can't!  That's what James has been saying, and I have been saying.  It's a package deal.  You are either NNBD and get the new features, or you're in legacy mode.  Nothing inbetween.

Comment: @iDecode 2.12 not being a breaking version means that you can safely replace your existing 2.x SDK installation with it.  That is all.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz "How can I enable my code to use 2.12 feature without breaking anything", your response is "You ... can't" Hence proved. `2.12` is a breaking change -- or maybe you are trying to say something else but it isn't clear enough  (at least for me).

Comment: @jamesdlin Sir, if I can safely replace my existing `2.x` (which is `2.6.0` in my post) with `2.12`, why is it breaking the code.

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm sorry if you're getting disturbed with this post, you can ignore it but if you can come up with a simple assertive statement I'll be really grateful.

Comment: @iDecode As explained multiple times, it breaks your code because you *opted-in* to requiring 2.12 language features by requiring 2.12 as the minimum SDK version in your `pubspec.yaml` file.  Replacing the SDK *and doing nothing else* should not break your code.

Comment: @jamesdlin What does it mean to replace the SDK, isn't it replacing `2.6.0` with `2.12.0`? If yes, then this is the only thing I did and it broke the code. Anyways, thanks for answering, I'm not fully satisfied but I'll accept your answer for all your efforts.

Comment: Replacing the SDK means removing the old SDK installation and installing the new one.  That's it.  You keep seeming to interpret that as being something more.  Modifying your `pubspec.yaml` (which you acknowledge that you did) is a *separate* action. By setting `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`, you are explicitly stating that your code is compatible with and requires language features from Dart 2.12. But if you haven't migrated your code to null safety, your code is *not* compatible with the 2.12 *language*, so you should *not* modify your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: Perhaps some more concrete examples would help.  The SDK is more than just the language.  Installing the Dart 2.12 SDK could, for example, allow you to take advantage of better optimizations from the compiler, new lints supported by the analyzer, formatting changes from the formatter, and bug fixes in the standard library.  When you install SDK 2.12 and leave `sdk: ">=2.6.0 < 3.0.0"`, you're still *using* the 2.12 SDK.  Your existing code should *not* be broken.  When you run `dart --version`, it will say `2.12`.  You just aren't using the *language features* from 2.12.

Comment: I do think it's a fair argument that 2.12 could have be numbered as, say 3.0, which probably also would have been nice from a marketing standpoint and probably would have been less confusing.

Comment: @jamesdlin Your 2nd last comment "Perhaps some  ... from 2.12" is what I was looking for especially this "When you install SDK 2.12 and leave sdk: ">=2.6.0 < 3.0.0", you're still using the 2.12 SDK." . I didn't know about SDK and settings sdk in `pubspec` were two different things. Maybe the question was dumb but once again I'm so thankful to you for making a dumb (like me) explain things this clearly. Thank you so very much sir. And I'm really sorry for the confusion, I was thinking that setting 2.12 means using Dart 2.12 SDK. But only a pro like you could have made it this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Dart 2.12 didn't break the code.  You did.  If you change the minsdk to 2.12.0, it won't work until you fix everything, because it's now running (as you asked it to do) in NNBD mode.  Dart 2.12 was happy to run it for you in non-null-safe mode, but you changed it.  So, no, this is not a breaking change.  Legacy code still runs fine with Dart running in legacy mode.

Comment: Can you please clarify "Dart 2.12 was happy to run it for you in non-null-safe mode, but you changed it".

Comment: Put the sdk setting back the way it was.  Dart 2.12 will happily run your legacy code in legacy mode.  Nothing is broken, unless you want to migrate to NNBD, and then apparently you have some fixing to do, which "dart migrate" can take care of pretty automatically.

Comment: Ok, if I put it back to 2.6.0, can I still use `int ?` as you said Dart 2.12 will happily run my code, I should then be able to use nullables + flow analysis, returning statement etc in my 2.6.0 code, right?

Comment: No.  2.12 is all or nothing.  You either get the new protection (compile time null safety) and new features (required, late, ? and !), *or* you get old syntax and behavior (run-time null safety).  Your choice.

Comment: Correct, so now please tell me how Dart 2.12 can run my legacy code? It does break it.

Comment: When you put 2.6 in your minsdk, as it was before, it is 2.12 running your legacy code *in legacy mode*.  Thus, it's not 2.12 that's a breaking change, it's *using* 2.12 in NNBD mode that's a breaking changee.  That's why the release of 2.12 is a non-breaking change, and why there won't be any more releases of 2.11 and earlier.  In fact, 2.13 is almost out: I'm running it on dev channel right now.

Comment: I just don't get this line, 2.12 isn't a breaking change but using it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231008/discussion-between-randal-schwartz-and-idecode).