# In the absence of a `pubspec.yaml` file, what determines whether I'm opting in to null safety?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I understand that if I `cd /tmp` and then `dart create code`, I get `environment:<newline> sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'` in `/tmp/code/pubspec.yaml`, which tells me that even though I'm running Dart v. 2.12.3, this (default) configuration does not opt into null safety by default.

But what if I create an empty directory (`mkdir /tmp/code`), generate a one-liner program (`echo "String a; " > /tmp/code/prog.dart`), chdir (`cd /tmp/code`), then run (`dart prog.dart`), where will dart look for `.dart_data/package_config.json` and `package_config.json`?

**Update**

I'm starting to suspect that the absence of a `pubspec.yaml` is not a sanctioned use case for Dart programming. The presence of `pubspec.yaml` is the only way that a package can be installed, for example (`dart pub add <package-name>`). The ransom result I'm getting (with null safety in one directory; without in another) remains a puzzle, but perhaps if `pubspec.yaml` is omitted, then consistency might be too much to ask for.

Comment: Null-safety is opt-in.  The mechanism for opting-in is to set Dart 2.12 (or greater) as the minimum required version in your `pubspec.yaml` file.  Otherwise it is assumed that you intend for your Dart code to be compatible with earlier versions.  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67045319/

Comment: @jamesdlin  I see. I rephrased the question to clarify. Can you see how two directories, both lacking a `pubspec.yaml` file, would trigger the error in one case (hence opting into null safety) and would not trigger an error in the other (opting out)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language-version marked in your `.dart_tool/package_config.json` file determines whether you have null safety. If the language version for your package is 2.12 or above, null safety is enabled.

That file is generated by Pub when you run `dart pub get` or `dart pub upgrade`, based on your `pubspec.yaml` file, and the pubspec files of your resolved dependencies.

Each Dart library can override the language version for that library by adding a `//@dart=2.9` comment at the start of a library (and every part file of the library, if it uses parts).

If you have no `package_config.json` file, the *current* default is to look for an old-style `.packages` file. If one is found, all language versions are set to 2.7, the language version of the SDK before introducing the `package_config.json` file and language versioning. Dart will stop looking for this old file eventually.

(The `.dart_tool` library and `.packages` file is searched for in the directory of the Dart file you're running, then in each parent directory of this until reaching the root, or until finding something).

If no `.packages` file is found either, the default is that you are using the *most recent* language version supported by the compiler.
That likely means null safety is enabled. You can use a `//@dart=2.9` comment to disable it (and all other later language features).

Comment: I'm still missing something. I rephrased the question. Could you clarify where Dart looks for `.dart_data/package_config.json` and `package_config.json`?

Comment: Add description, and fixed typo in name, it's `.dart_tool/` actually.